# Ubuntu 20.04 Install .netframeworkv4.8 in the command line ONLY

Tags: command-line

I have tried in so many ways to install .net framework4.8 in Linux using the command line, but every single installer I can find wants to open a window, which using the command line will not allow me to do.

How do I install .net framework4.8 using ONLY the command line, without any other windows wanting to open.

thx.

Comment: Are you talking about .NET Core, or the Windows .NET framework in WINE?  I have to ask because one has a CLI install method, and the other does not.

Comment: I tried using wine, no good. Tried downloading the files from microsoft, all of them want to open a window.  Here is a thought, if I installed Ubuntu Server CL only would it come with the .net framework4.8 files preinstalled?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Are you trying to install .NET Core, or the WINE / Windows Only .NET Frameworks?  I assume Core but i'm trying to figure out what you're working with.  There is no way to ship .NET pre-installed in Ubuntu because it's not part of the Ubuntu repos (and isn't 'free' software technically so can't be in the standard repos for that reason)

Comment: I guess the wine version, as some people told me to use wine to fix the problem.

Comment: It'd be easier to know what your core problem is rather than trying to solve the proverbial [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that is the reason for your question.  WINE installers of .NET are the Windows GUI installers.  There is not a CLI-only installation option/variation that can be used in Wine to install the framework.  If you're *needing* a Windows only tool, it sounds like you need Windows, not WINE/Linux.  (Again, the XY problem, because you're trying to solve a potential solution not the underlying core problem).

Comment: I get this error message when trying to compile a working exe for my mmorpg using the linux command line:
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1241,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/home/jburns/ServUO/Server/Server.csproj]

Comment: that project you need there will require a **complete** Windows build environment.  Attempting to hack this in Linux to make VSCode, etc. work with .NET 4.8 (which is NOT .NET Core) will not work properly, because WINE isn't a full environment for *development* either.  You will need to spin up a Windows VM in your environment if you insist on using Linux as your main driver OS and use that for your Windows devel/build environment. Your project requires .NET **Framework** 4.8, not .NET **Core**, and unfortunately will need a full Windows build env.